# moving or Storing text using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to move text between text boxes, but failed.
what is wrong with this approach.

```
 <html>
<script>
function fill(){
document.getElementById("text2").value = document.test.text1.value 
}
</script>

<form name="test" id="test">
<input type="text" name="text1" id="text1"/>
<input type="text" name="text2" id="text2" value=""/>
<button name="b" onclick="fill()">move</button>
</form>
</html>
```

Comment: Why are you accessing the different text boxes in different ways? Also - what does the javascript error console say?

Comment: do you think this cause the problem, what I want is to store some text in some where before sending it to database. I am not using console and not familiar with it , please can you explain more? thanks

Comment: It might be. First, be consistent. Then check the errors you are getting from the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One reason is the button is submitting the form. That needs to be suppressed. Also, avoid inline (aka DOM zero) event declarations and bind the event more formally:

```
function fill(evt){
    document.getElementById("text2").value = document.test.text1.value;
    evt.preventDefault();
}
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    document.querySelector('#test button').addEventListener('click', fill, false);
}, false);
```

I'm using a few modern methods there, so you might need to tweak it if you need to support older IEs, but you get the idea.

Note also that, if the fill function is used only for this button and not elsewhere, instead of defining it with a name and referencing it as I do here, you could reference it as an anonymous function directly in the event binding. Look up "anonymous functions" for more on that.